# Python: How to express a division of factorials in decimal format?

Tags: python, factorial, floating-point-conversion

I'm trying to obtain the coefficients for Laguerre polynomials, this involves division of factorials, this is my code:

```
Coeficientes=[]
def Ln(n):
    for m in xrange(n+1):
        Coeficientes.append(((-1)**m *factorial(n))/(factorial(n-m)*factorial(m)*factorial(m)))
    print "Coeficiente de grado", m, ":", Coeficientes[m]
```

The problem is that when I must obtain the coefficient with value 0.5, i get 0.

Example

```
Ln(2)
```

Result:

```
Coeficiente de grado 0 : 1
Coeficiente de grado 1 : -2
Coeficiente de grado 2 : 0
```

But must say :

```
Coeficiente de grado 2 : 0.5
```

If i write Ln(2.) it returns me an error: Integer argument expected, got float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got `Coeficiente de grado 2 : 0` and not `Coeficiente de grado 2 : 0.5` because `factorial` accept only integer, alternative way is to use `math.gamma(x)`

`gamma` is an extension of the factorial function to real numbers. (if you are using python  2.7 or 3.2)

see [pydoc here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/math.html#math.gamma)

Comment: Thanks, I had not thought

Comment: @DianaPineda, please mark my answer if helps and an upvote will be a plus to me. Thanks :'D

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the function `factorial`. This is only able to evaluate on positive integers. You should use `math.gamma(n)` to evaluate any real numbers instead(non-integer or integer).

`from math import gamma
print (((-1)**m *gamma(n))/(gamma(n-m)*gamma(m)*gamma(m)))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast one of the numbers as float to prevent everything from being treated as an integer: `(-1)**float(m)` or `(-1.0)**m`

```
Coeficientes=[]
def Ln(n):
    for m in xrange(n+1):
        Coeficientes.append(((-1)**float(m) *factorial(n))/(factorial(n-m)*factorial(m)*factorial(m)))
        print "Coeficiente de grado", m, ":", Coeficientes[m]
```

When doing division with integers, Python will cast the result as a int. For example, `7/5` will result in `1`. But `7.0/5` results in `1.4`.

Decimal is even more accurate and avoids rounding errors. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: When I write Ln(2.0), too, it returns me the error because "factorial" only accepts integers :(

Comment: @DianaPineda - I was too hasty. There is only one spot you need to cast as float: `(-1)**float(m)`

Comment: @DianaPineda perhaps a better link is https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial